# Listar las carpetas de una ruta (obtener subdirectorios)

Tags: php, archivo

Lo que estoy buscando es hacer un array que contenga solo los nombres de carpetas (directorios) de una ruta dada.

Intenté con scandir():

```
$scan = scandir(realpath(__dir__));
for ($i = 0; $i < count($scan); $i++) {
    if (is_file(dirname(__file__) . '\\' . $scan[$i])) {
    //Si es un archivo Eliminalo en su posicion $i
        array_splice($scan, $i, 1);
    }
}
```

Pero todavía queda un archivo .sql en el array que no debería estar ahí:

```
[0] => . [1] => .. [3] => controladores [7] => modelos [8] => vistas [9] => zonaedu.sql
                                                //en el último elemento --> ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

¿A qué se debe esto?

Comment: *Lo que estoy buscando es hacer un array que contenga solo los nombres de carpetas.*... Tu código no hace eso, no con `z` ni con no `z`... Este por ejemplo, lo haría: **`$dirs = array_filter(glob('*'), 'is_dir');
print_r( $dirs);`**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando una `\` en vez  de `/`, o mejor aún `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`. Y tanto is_dir() como is_file() necesitan la ruta completa.

**Listar todos los subdirectorios de una carpeta** (no recursivo)

1. Una alternativa, si también te interesan eliminar los enlaces simbólicos es usando [**is_dir()**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.is-dir.php):

   ```
   $carpetaBase = realpath(__dir__);
   $resultado = array();

   foreach(scandir($carpetaBase) as $carpeta) {
       if ($carpeta != '.' && $carpeta != '..' && is_dir($carpetaBase . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $carpeta)) {
           $resultado[] = $carpeta;
       }
   }

   print_r($resultado);
   ```

2. O podemos usar [**glob()**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.glob.php) con la opción `GLOB_ONLYDIR`:

   ```
   $carpetaBase = getcwd();
   $resultado = array();

   foreach(glob($carpetaBase . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $carpeta) {
       $resultado[] = basename($carpeta);
   }

   print_r($resultado);
   ```

3. O con la clase [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/es/class.directoryiterator.php):

   ```
   $resultado = array();
   $di = new DirectoryIterator($carpetaBase);
   foreach ($di as $carpeta) {
       if ($carpeta->isDir() && !$carpeta->isDot()) {
           $resultado[] = $carpeta->getFilename();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: De hecho, no es tan necesario `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`, ya que PHP siempre va a interpretar bien una `/` (independientemente del sistema), pero viene bien si estamos armando una carpeta que después podamos procesar con un explode()

Comment: Gracias, no sabia que el  separador por defecto (\) iba a ser perjudicial.
lo que hice fue cambiarlos con $carpetaBase = str_replace('\\', '/', $carpetaBase);

y luego:
foreach (scandir($carpetaBase) as $carpeta) {
    if ($carpeta != '.' and $carpeta != '..' and is_dir($carpetaBase . '/' . $carpeta)) {
        $resultado[] = $carpeta;
    }
}

Me salen solo las carpetas: Array ( [0] => controladores [1] => modelos [2] => vistas ) 

Gracias @Mariano